# vba@excel_highlight the empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating an excel file with column A to H are mandatory cells.
This excel file will be passing around for input. 
So, I would like to highlight the empty cells as a reminder.

I have written the following code...

```
Sub Highlight_Cell()
Dim Rng As Range

For Each Rng In Range("A2:H20") 
If Rng.Value = "" Then
Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ‘yellow
Else
Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 'blank
End If
Next Rng
   MsgBox "Please fill in all mandatory fields highlighted in yellow."
End Sub
```

However, I would like to set the range from A2 to the last row that contains data within column A to H. 
Also, display the message box only when empty cell exist.
Could you please advise how should I amend?

Million Thanks!!!

Comment: if the data in colulmn A:H can be blank then how do you know which is the last rows that contains data within A:H? Is there another data section outside this range that sets the limit?

Answer (score 0):

This is a VBA solution that prevents the user from saving until the desired range is filled (acknowledging Gserg's comment that that the last row is one that has at least one cell entered)

In the second portion you can either add your sheet index directly, `Set ws = Sheets(x)` for position x, or `Set ws = Sheets("YourSheet")` for a specific sheet name

The code will only highlight truly blank cells within A to H of this sheet till the last entered cell (using SpecialCells as a shortcut). Any such cells will be selected by the code on exit

1. Put this code in the ThisWorkbook module (so it fires whenever the user tries to close the file)

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   bCheck = False
   Call CheckCode
   If bCheck Then Cancel = True
   End Sub
   ```
2. Put this code in a standard module

   ```
   Public bCheck As Boolean
   Sub CheckCode()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim rng1 As Range
   Dim rng2 As Range
   bCheck = False
   'works on sheet 1, change as needed
   Set ws = Sheets(1)
   Set rng1 = ws.Columns("A:H").Find("*", ws.[a1], xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows)
   If rng1 Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox "No Cells in columns A:H on " & ws.Name & " file will now close", vbCritical
       Exit Sub  
   End If
   Set rng2 = ws.Range(ws.[a1], ws.Cells(rng1.Row, "H"))
   On Error Resume Next
   Set rng2 = rng2.SpecialCells(xlBlanks)
   On Error GoTo 0
   If rng2 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   bCheck = True
   rng2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
   MsgBox "Please fill in all mandatory fields on " & ws.Name & " highlighted in yellow", vbCritical, "Save Cancelled!"
   Application.Goto rng2.Cells(1)
   End Sub
   ```